# How to exclude multiple users from find command result in tcsh?

Tags: find, tcsh

I want to exclude a group of users from find results, they don't belong to the same unix group, this is not the best way, right ?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_pattern_*' ! -user user1 ! -user user2 ...
```

Can I pass in the users as a string or an array? maybe with awk ?

Comment: in what form/format is the list of users right now?

Answer (score 0):

On a cshell you can cobble up the `find` command to perform the job as follows:

```
 #!/bin/tcsh -f

 # persona non grata
 set png = ( \
    user1 \
    user2 \
    user3 \
    user4 \
 ) 

 # build dynamically a portion of the `find` command
 set cmd = ( `printf '! -user %s\n' $png:q` )

 # now fire the generated find command
 find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_pattern_*'  $cmd:q
```

Comment: I _recognise_ that code...  :-)

Comment: But if you're doing it in a separate script, it may as well be a `sh` script. Well at least in my humble opinion.  Neat that you can shift an array like that though.

Comment: I just took your bash code and converted to equivalent csh.  The much maligned csh  has some nifty features too, like you saw, shift and the concept of arrays. I remember the Op was looking for a tcsh code.

Comment: @kusalananda hope that now you won't recognize the code. ☺️

Answer (score -1):

Except for the fact that `csh` does not like an unescaped exclamation mark, in the command line, your command looks OK and cannot be made better

Answer (score -1):

If you're happy to run it from a `/bin/sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# the users to avoid
set -- user1 user2 user3 user4

# create a list of 
# -o -user "username" -o -user "username" etc.
for user do
    set -- "$@" -o -user "$user"
    shift
done
shift # remove that first "-o"

# use the created array in the call to find
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_pattern_*' ! '(' "$@" ')'
```

Alternatively, to build the same sort of `! -user "username"` list that you use:

```
#!/bin/sh

# the users to avoid
set -- user1 user2 user3 user4

# create a list of 
# ! -user "username" ! -user "username" etc.
for user do
    set -- "$@" ! -user "$user"
    shift
done

# use the created array in the call to find
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_pattern_*' "$@"
```